# How do I access session variable from php in external javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, session-variables

I know this has been asked before but there's no explanation from start to finish. I have a `login.php` from which I want to get `$_SESSION['user_id']`

from

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

session_start();

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$select_data=mysql_query("select * from user where email='$email' and password='$password'");

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_data))
 {
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id']; //The variable want to access from ext.js

  echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "fail";
 }
 exit();
}
?>
```

By the way, this authenication works fine

My Main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'connect.php';
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_id']; //works fine
//;
?>
<body>
//contents
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="postad.js"></script> //the script from which I want to get $SESSION_['user_id']

</body>
```

I want this variable to insert later on in a database. Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo "<script>var user = \"$_SESSION['user_id']\";</script>";`

Comment: Where do I put that, because I get errors when I put in my login result

Comment: In the page instead of the echo you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call php variable in external js file then you have to store value in input.

**Main.php**

```
<body>
<input type="hidden" value="$SESSION_['user_id']" class="user_id">
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="postad.js"></script> //the script from which I want to get $SESSION_['user_id']

</body>
```

**postad.js**

```
$(function(){
    var user_id = $('.user_id').val();
    alert(user_id);
});
```

And if you want to use in same file then you can directly use php echo.

**Main.php**

```
<body>
    //content..

<script>
    var user_id = "<?php echo $SESSION_['user_id'] ?>";
</script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="postad.js"></script> // console.log(user_id); that file you'll get that id.
</body>
```

Comment: Well explained but it shows me an error: UncaughtSyntaxError at the `function` line. Should I mention that the login is done via a modal popup to the page doesn't reload just some elements change, so maybe that might be the problem?

Comment: I given you two solution which one you used? see answer edited.

Comment: Just had to put it this way `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>" class="user_id">`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign session id value to a JavaScript variable to make it available for JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'connect.php';
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_id']; //works fine
//;
?>
<body>
//contents
<script>
    var sessionId = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>";
</script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="postad.js"></script> // "sessionId" variable should be available for the script
</body>
```

Comment: okay I did that and tried to test via javascript if it had something, `($btn).click(function(){console.log(sessionId; )})`and nothing showed